# Java EE 6 CDI interceptor vs dynamic java proxy

Tags: java, proxy, cdi, interceptor

I am learning the CDI AOP specification (`@Interceptor`).

If we use CDI AOP interceptors the use of `newProxyInstance`(Dynamic Java Proxy) will be deprecated. Am I correct?

Comment: What do you mean by deprecated?

Comment: what i really want to ask is why use one over the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your question, because I think you're talking about AOP.  The Interceptor spec (assuming you mean Java EE 7) is specific to Java EE.  You would still use java proxy is you want non-EE support (e.g. it can run in an SE app without many other dependencies).  It doesn't meant that the SE version is deprecated (in fact, CDI leverages it to do its work).